# Can "Rinse off the apple/the apple off" or "Rinse the dirt off" be used as a short form of "Rinse the dirt off the apple"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, phrase-usage

According to [the dictionary](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/rinse), we can say

> She rinsed the dirt off the lettuce.
>
> He rinsed the soap out of the cup.

And we can also say

> Rinse (off) the apple before you eat it.
>
> rinse (out) a cup

or

> [Rinse the cup out before use.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rinse-out#rinse_pvg_1)

So, I inferred that if the context is clear, "**Rinse off the apple**" or "**Rinse the apple off**" or "**Rinse the dirt off**" can be used as a short form of "**Rinse the dirt off the apple**".

And "**Rinse out the cup**" or "**Rinse the cup out**" or "**Rinse the soap out**" can be used as a short form of "**Rinse the soap out of the cup**".

**But that could be ambiguous.**

Say there is some fish scales on a cutting board

If we say "**Rinse the fish scales off**", it could mean "**Rinse the fish scales off the cutting board**" (the scales is on the cutting board) or ""**Rinse the dirt off the fish scales**" (there is some dirt on some big fish scales).

Similarly, can "**wipe the dirt off**" or "**wipe off the table**" or "**wipe the table off**" be used as a short form of "**wipe the dirt off the table**"?

**Note:** I have a feeling that American people sometimes say "**wipe off the table**" or "**wipe the table off**", but that is not common in British. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a native speaker's perspective, the 'off' is unnecessary as the brackets in you questions quote blocks imply you already know.

[Rinse](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/rinse) is a synonym for clean. So simply saying rinse the apple is ok.

That said 'Rinse off' is perfectly acceptable as used on [idioms dictionary.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rinse+off)

> Please rinse off your dirty dishes before you put them in the dishwasher.

The adjective dirty here confuses things a little given the nature of the question but it is hopeful clear that 'dirty' is not required in the quoted sentence.

Comment: Agreed. It's obvious that the purpose of rinsing the apple is to clean it, so you don't need to mention the dirt (and who would wash fish scales?).